# Whats is the best way to create a model of a user in swiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

I am trying to create a model to represent user data that i get from a api but the data is in a json format and the structure is this:

[image]

This is how i have my user Model structured:

User Model class:

[image]

And then since the address consists of children i created a different model for it which looks like this:

[image]

So for the address of a user it is type Address which then has the appropriate variables and same applies for the company and geo location.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to represent this data as i keep getting a 'User does not conform to protocol Decodable'

and i also get this error on the address variable:
"Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'Address' does not conform to 'Decodable'"

What is the best way that i can fix this?

Comment: Try not to post images of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to work with codable automatic implementations, all types in parent `codable` should conform to `codable` too.

In your case, Since you want the `User` to be a codable, all the following should confotm codable too:

```
Int
String
Address
Company
```

Almost all default standard types are preconformed to codable. so you just need to make the `Address` and `Comapny` conform to that.

Note that this is going deeper and deeper on all types. For example when you try to conform for the `Address`, the `GeoLocation` should be a `Codable` too